# Continuous data on line chart using weeks in Power BI

Tags: date, powerbi, linechart, x-axis

I am trying to make a single line chart by putting weeks on x-axis and revenue on y-axis. However when add week data on x-axis it is all messed up.

I don't have any option to choose from categorical and continuous. I also have an issue that x-axis is long and not formatted to fit. Check the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Start of Week` column needs be of Date data type.
Select this column then go to `Column tools` in the ribbon. At the top left, change Data type to Date.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out eventually. For some reason my columns were not saved after formatting.